# Couldn't get the value to the xslt variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a stored procedure which returns item names as xml.I  use this in xslt code to return the names.and I want to get the names to a xslt variable.I tried my code like

```
<xsl:variable name="Item" 
  select="shop:ExecStoredProcedure(
           'kt_Item',
           concat('@Dcat:',$p//defaultcategory)
          )" />
<xsl:variable name="txt1" 
              select="$Item//TT[@TXT1]"/>
  <textarea>
    <xsl:value-of select="$txt1"/>
  </textarea>
```

the output xml is like

```
<root>
<item>
<Column1>
<TT TXT1="Item3" />
<TT TXT1="Item2" />
<TT TXT1="Item1" />
</Column1>
</item>
</root>
```

but in my code  I can't get the names.Waht is the problem ?anybody know?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do; you refer a couple of times to "the names", but nothing in the XML you are copying to the output is called 'name'. Do you mean that instead of writing the TT elements to the output, you want to write the values of the TXT1 attribute to the output?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that your `ExecStoredProcedure` return value is a string from the xslt point of view (even if the sting contains XML).

XSLt-1.0 can't reinterpret a string as  XML. Depending on your environment (xlst processor) you may use a extension `node-set()` to do this.

If you can use this extension you can try something like:

```
 <xsl:variable name="txt1" select="exsl:node-set($Item)//TT[@TXT1]">
```

Comment: I tried But  the result I getting is  


<TT TXT1="Item1" /><TT TXT1="Item2" /><TT TXT1="Item3" />

Comment: Hm seems I do not understand what your expected output is, but the xpath seems to work because `TT[@TXT1]` looks for all TT with attribute @TXT.